# How can I add a property to the window object in Chrome using Applescript?

Tags: applescript, google-chrome, javascript

In Chrome's JavaScript Console, I can type the following:

```
window.myVar = "myValue";
```

I can then access `myVar` from the window context, where it returns `"myValue"`. Excellent.

However, if I do the following in Applescript:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    execute front window's active tab javascript "window.myVar = 'myValue';"
end tell
```

This execute statement appears to run when the script is called. No errors are thrown, and the Chrome window exists. But when I try to reference `myVar` from the window context, only `undefined` is ever returned. For testing purposes, I added in an alert statement after that declaration - the alert WILL fire, but `myVar` remains unset.

Now, in Safari, using `do JavaScript` with this same code works as if I'd typed the code directly into the console - `myVar` returns a value.

Why doesn't Chrome fire these statements when called by Applescript when it can be done manually?
(Chrome 51.0.2704.84, OS X 10.11.5)

Answer (score 1):

I discovered a workaround. Might not be the best, but the following line executes the JavaScript I have in mind while also setting properties of `window`:

```
tell front window of application "Google Chrome"
    set URL of active tab to "javascript:" & window.myVar = "myValue"
end tell
```

Using this, `myVar` properly returns `"myValue"`. Nice.